# How to use columns in a DataGridView to influence MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

Currently I'm working on a project where a person can import an excel file (containing stock quantity) into a DataGridView and then export it into a MySQL table. When exporting to MySQL, I want to take the stock quantity in the file away from another table in MySQL (like if you were moving stock). So far I have the importing/exporting business sorted but I can't figure out away to deduct the value from the table.

I'm currently trying

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2 Step +1
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE `test`.`new_table` SET `Quantity` = `Quantity` - '@Quantity' WHERE `ID`= ('@ID')", MysqlConn)
COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Quantity").Value.ToString()

COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()

Next
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. I've tried assigning names to them via Dim as well but I didn't have any luck with it. If you have any advice, I'd be glad to hear it! Thanks

Comment: Couple of things that stick out - you don't need to put the parameter names in quotes inside the SQL string, so just use @Quantity instead of '@Quantity' etc. Also you're passing the values in as VarChars, so they're strings. You'll need to pass them in as a the correct type (especially if you're going to do some math with them). Hopefully the Quantity field isn't a VarChar otherwise you're in for a tough time.

Comment: @Slugsie Thanks for getting back to me! I re-typed the code the wrong when I was writing the question (I'm on my phone and the codes on a desktop) , fortunately in the real thing the quantity is in INT32 format except for the ending where it's .ToString. Would it help if I changed the ending to an integer as well?

Comment: If the DB field 'Quantity' is a numeric type, pass the parameter in as the same type. Don't convert the number to a string, why would you do that? You can't perform maths on strings.

Comment: @Slugsie fun point of note; mysql will treat it as a string for you anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should look more like:

```
Command = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE `test`.`new_table` SET `Quantity` = `Quantity` - @Quantity WHERE `ID`= @ID", MysqlConn)
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 0)
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", 0)



For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2 

  Dim c = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells

  Command.Parameters("@ID").Value = Convert.ToInt32(c("ID").Value))
  Command.Parameters("@Quantity").Value = Convert.ToInt32(c("Quantity").Value))

  Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

Next
```

But really your data should be in a typed datatable, then your code would look somewhat nicer:

```
Command = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE `test`.`new_table` SET `Quantity` = `Quantity` - @Quantity WHERE `ID`= @ID", MysqlConn)
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 0)
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", 0)



For Each r In someTable

  Command.Parameters("@ID").Value = r.ID
  Command.Parameters("@Quantity").Value = r.Quantity

  Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

Next
```

Comment: I've stumbled across just 1 issue with the code and I'm not sure how to resolve it. The ID is meant to be a string/varchar. I changed Convert.ToInt32(c("ID"). Value) to Convert.ToString(c("ID"). Value). Now it seems to have an issue with COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", 0). It triggers an error saying "Input string was not in a correct format". I tried getting rid of the " WithValue" bit but then the error is "Input string was not in a correct format". I tried messing around with the 0 after "ID" with little success as well.

Comment: Set up the parameter using a string: `Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", "1234")`, that way when you later put a real string into it with `Convert.ToString(c("ID"). Value)` there will be no complaints

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries. DOn't forget to mark the question as answered by clicking the grey check mark. This lets other people know just aty a glance from the dashboard, that the question is answered